# How to match and remove whitespace html markup using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, ckeditor

I have a need to strip out whitespace markup from a string of HTML. By "markup" I mean any empty HTML elements that contain entities or characters that would render as whitespace in a web browser. For example

```
<p>&nbsp;&zwnj;</p>Test <div>  </div><br/><span> okay </span>
```

...should become

```
Test <span> okay </span>
```

The point is to remove elements from the DOM that would not be visible or would only add extra line breaks.

This would solve a problem I encounter supporting an online editor where users cut-n-paste content from Word. Sometimes the clipboard grabs incomplete elements. For example, a closing p tag. When pasted into the editor, the incomplete element is healed with the insertion of the opening p tag. This is when I have the opportunity to apply regular expressions and DOM manipulation to clean up these surprisingly very problematic elements. Jquery is the only library I have available to leverage.

Comment: If down voters would have the decency to comment I would appreciate that.

Comment: try `/<.+?>(&nbsp;|\s)+<\/.+?>|<br\/>/g` (edited)

Answer (score 2):

`/<.+?>(&nbsp;|&zwnj;|\s)+<\/.+?>|<br\/>/g` does the trick for me:

```js
let str = '<p>&nbsp;&zwnj;</p>Test <div>  </div><br/><span> okay </span>';
let regex = /<.+?>(&nbsp;|&zwnj;|\s)+<\/.+?>|<br\/>/g;

console.log(str.replace(regex, ""));
```

Comment: This is pretty good, it works for my trivial example, but I didn't enumerate all possibilities. I'll try to edit my question.

Comment: Just saw your edit (because I don't get notifications for edits) and made an edit in return.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea: loop through all the elements in the DOM and see if their `innerHtml` or `innerText` is white space something like this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    if(all[i].innerHTML == "" || all[i].innerText == ""){           
        all[i].parentElement.removeChild(all[i]);
    };
}
```

Comment: I've tried something close to this. One draw back is performance. Since the user is actively participating in the cut-n-paste operation any delay is very obvious. For large operations, the users may have already begun typing before the iteration has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution that should remove all empty tags in the body.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

function removeEmptyChildren(node){
  let children = node.children;
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    if(children[i].children){
      removeEmptyChildren(children[i]);
    }
    if(!children[i].textContent.trim().length){
      node.removeChild(children[i]);
      i--;
    }
  }
}

removeEmptyChildren(body);
```